# .NET WebBrowser Control and Refresh

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a simple WinForm with a WebBrowser control on it that displays an image from the Web. The image is refreshed according to the Timer1.
It works fine until I press *F5* or use *'Refresh'* option from the browser's context menu. Then I get a blank page and I have to restart the program.
Why is that?
I want to be able to update manually if need be without waiting for Timer1.
Any suggestions?
I am using Visual Basic Express 2010.

```
 Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body><img src='http://example.com/image.jpg'></body></html>"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        WebBrowser1.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing to `DocumentText` does not change `Url`, and `Url` is requeried upon refresh, so when you press F5, the browser refreshes `about:blank`. I'm actually wondered `.Refresh()` worked for you.

You want something like:

```vb
Private Shared ReadOnly about_blank As Uri = New Uri("about:blank")

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Url = about_blank
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigated
    If e.Url = about_blank Then
        WebBrowser1.Document.Write("<html><body><img src='http://example.com/image.jpg'></body></html>")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    WebBrowser1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I wonder why the `WebBrowser.Refresh()` method works differently from **F5** or the **Refresh** in the context menu. I would expect them to be the same. Has something to do with caching?